# MS AppCenter build No scheme found for project.xcworkspace

Tags: git, react-native, appcenter

I'm trying to create a React Native iOS build in MS AppCenter and getting the following error:

> No scheme found for project.xcworkspace

[image: No scheme found error in App Center]

It's probably an issue related to my git repository structure. My git root and project root isn't the same directory. It looks like this: `git_root > react_native_project_root > ios > project.xcworkspace`

Any ideas how can I resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption was correct after I've changed git structure from `git_root > react_native_project_root > ios > project.xcworkspace` to `git_root > ios > project.xcworkspace`, issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, described it in [AppCenter: build React-Native project which is 2 levels deep in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55887561/291695).
From official AppCenter docs:

> For best performance, the analysis is currently limited to four directory levels including the root of your repository.

So, your xcode project happens to be too deep in the hierarchy.
I used the same workaround as you did - I changed the folder structure.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the .xcscheme files are not tracked by Git LFS.