# AppCenter: build React-Native project which is 2 levels deep in Git

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I'm setting up react-native build in AppCenter.

Everything works on test projects, but in a real repository I'm facing the following issue:

> For best performance, the analysis is currently limited to four directory levels including the root of your repository.
>   (Quote from [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/react-native/android/#3-setting-up-your-first-build))

My package.json is 2 levels deep (`/folder1/folder2/package.json`), so `build.gradle` is located 5 levels deep (`/folder1/folder2/android/app/build.gradle`).

So when I set up the build in AppCenter I'm able to specify the `Project` field (pointing to my `package.json`), but `Build Variant` combobox is empty.

Is there any solution for that? Can I specify `Build Variant` manually?

P.S. If I simply move the project one folder above - everything works fine. But I can't do that in my monorepository.

Comment: I am having a very similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570961/app-center-shows-no-build-variants-for-react-native-android. Did you get this resolved?

Comment: I worked around it. Basically, I created a separate repo with 1-level less nesting, and I'm copying my folder to another repo on each push (via TeamCity). AppCenter is configured against this 'flat' repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround we are currently using: we created a separate repo with 1-level less nesting, and I'm copying my folder to another repo on each push (via TeamCity).
So, having a repo structure like this:

```
project
│───frontend
│   └───shared
│   └───web
│   └───react-native
│       │   package.json  --> this is the folder we want to build in AppCenter
│       │   ...
│   
└───backend
    └── somefile.cs
```

We set up git-hooks to copy the `frontend` folder to another repo:

```
root
└───shared
└───web
└───react-native
    │   package.json  --> this is the folder we want to build in AppCenter
    │   ...
```

So we got one level less deep repository which is ok for AppCenter.