# App Center shows no build variants for React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to set up a build for a React Native app on App Center.
I have linked the app to the Azure Devops Repository, and selected the branch and attempted to create a build.

However, when I try to create the build, it finds the package.json but does not find any build variants:

[image]

I have confirmed that it is finding the package.json for the app (I remove it and it complains).
I know that the build variants come from the build types in the build.gradle, which has a release variant in it.

I've googled the heck out of this and burned two evenings on it.
I have another project that builds just fine, and I cannot see the difference between them.

Why is AppCenter not able to pick up the build variants? How do I configure them?

Comment: make sure your develop brach is up to date with the latest version of your code, also can you edit and add your app build.gradle? I'm also using AppCenter and i building successfully

Comment: Thanks @NatiSholmanOskar I also have a working app and can't figure the difference. I'm using the main develop branch (have also tried others). It can find the package.json, but no the build.gradle. The build.gradle file is there and I can edit it

Comment: I have the same problem :( I suspect that the issue may be that my solution is a yarn workspaces setup. I believe that the gradle file is not found because it is 2 more levels down the folder tree compared to a default RN project. But it would be nice have it confirmed and fantastic to find a workaround :)

Comment: @JennyPettersson I've been working with MS support on this over the last week. Currently I've discovered that if I upload the exact same repos up to GitHub and hook that into the build, it works fine. When using azure devops, it just doesn't find build.gradle. Weird, I though git was git! So my workaround at the moment is to have a second remote on the repos push to GitHub whenever I push to Azure DevOps. I can try moving the source to have fewer levels of folder depth to see if that makes a difference on Azure

Comment: Many thanks for sharing your findings Simon!! For now, I actually gave up and set up a pipeline in Azure Devops which build the apps and then publish them to App Center for distribution. My configuration is rather complicated with different product flavours so I probably would have ended up there eventually either way. I love the idea of having everything in the same place but so far I have had a lot of problems setting up the different parts of App Center, hopefully there will be more help to find once it is more mature :)

Comment: As an update, I have been liaising with MS on this. There current update is 'Hi we currently have limitation on how deep we search the code, and it varies depending on source host. This is why you see difference between GitHub and Azure DevOps. Could you try move your project one level up in Azure DevOps?' However, my packages.json is only two levels deep, and their own documentation states <= 4 is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question, the issue is a limitation currently on Azure DevOps.

As reported by MS and the maximum depth of the package.json is actually only two levels deep, not 4 levels as described in their documentation.